# Unknown host exception when trying to launch Mule project

Tags: java, maven, mule

It's an empty project, I'm just trying to get Mule up and running and I'm not sure what's wrong here. My JDk is configured correctly and my Maven dependencies haven't been changed or anything.

> INFO  2015-06-02 09:44:35,894 [main]
>   org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer:
>
> ---
>
> - Mule ESB and Integration Platform                                  *
> - Version: 3.6.0 Build: ed775fdb                                     *
> - MuleSoft, Inc.                                                     *
> - For more information go to                                         *
> - http://www.mulesoft.com/mule-esb-enterprise                        *
> - *
> - Server started: 6/2/15 9:44 AM                                     *
> - JDK: 1.7.0_55 (mixed mode)                                         *
> - OS: Windows 8.1 -  (6.3, amd64)                                    *
> - Host: OITLaptop (132.235.196.203)                                  *
>     ********************************************************************** INFO  2015-06-02 09:44:35,946 [main]
>     org.mule.module.launcher.coreextension.DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManager:
>     Initializing core extensions INFO  2015-06-02 09:44:35,946 [main]
>     com.mulesoft.mmc.agent.AgentCoreExtension: Mule Agent Core Extension
>     is DISABLED INFO  2015-06-02 09:44:35,982 [main]
>     com.mulesoft.mule.cluster.hazelcast.config.ClusterTicketFileLoader:
>     C:\Users\Alex\AnypointStudio\workspace.mule.mule\mule-cluster.properties
>     (The system cannot find the file specified) WARN  2015-06-02
>     09:44:35,987 [main]
>     com.mulesoft.mule.cluster.boot.ClusterCoreExtension: No cluster ID was
>     specified -- High Availability will be disabled: INFO  2015-06-02
>     09:44:36,119 [main]
>     com.mulesoft.mule.plugin.manager.MulePluginManager: Registering
>     plugin: mule-plugin-debugger-3.6.0 INFO  2015-06-02 09:44:36,161
>     [main]
>     org.mule.module.launcher.coreextension.DefaultMuleCoreExtensionManager:
>     Starting core extensions INFO  2015-06-02 09:44:36,175 [main]
>     org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: ==================
>     New Exploded Artifact: default INFO  2015-06-02 09:44:36,251 [main]
>     org.mule.module.launcher.domain.DefaultMuleDomain: 
>     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
> - New domain 'default'                                     +
>     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ INFO  2015-06-02 09:44:36,252 [main]
>     org.mule.module.launcher.domain.DefaultMuleDomain: 
>     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
> - Initializing domain 'default'                            +
>     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ INFO  2015-06-02 09:44:36,253 [main]
>     org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService: 
>     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
> - Started domain 'default'                                 +
>     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ INFO  2015-06-02 09:44:36,257 [main]
>     org.mule.module.launcher.ArtifactArchiveInstaller: Exploding a Mule
>     artifact archive:
>     file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb.zip
>     INFO  2015-06-02 09:44:36,668 [main]
>     org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
>     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
> - New app 'slack-notifications-esb'                        +
>     ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ INFO  2015-06-02 09:44:36,674 [main]
>     org.mule.module.launcher.MuleApplicationClassLoader:
>     [slack-notifications-esb] Loading the following jars:
>     ============================= file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar
>     file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb/lib/ftplet-api-1.0.6.jar
>     file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb/lib/ftpserver-core-1.0.6.jar
>     file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb/lib/hamcrest-core-1.1.jar
>     file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb/lib/jasypt-1.9.2.jar
>     file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb/lib/jasypt-spring31-1.9.2.jar
>     file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb/lib/jaxb-impl-2.2.5.1.jar
>     file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb/lib/jaxb-xjc-2.2.5.1.jar
>     file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb/lib/junit-4.9.jar
>     file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb/lib/mina-core-2.0.4.jar
>     file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb/lib/mockito-core-1.9.5.jar
>     file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb/lib/mockobjects-core-0.09.jar
>     file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb/lib/mule-module-reboot-3.6.0.jar
>     file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb/lib/objenesis-1.0.jar
>     file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb/lib/ojdbc6-12.1.0.1.jar
>     file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb/lib/spring-web-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar
>
>   ## file:/C:/Users/Alex/AnypointStudio/workspace/.mule/apps/slack-notifications-esb/lib/sshd-core-0.6.0.jar
>
> INFO  2015-06-02 09:44:36,759 [main]
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
>   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   + Initializing app 'slack-notifications-esb'               +
>   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ INFO  2015-06-02 09:44:36,965 [main]
>   org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising
>   RegistryBroker INFO  2015-06-02 09:44:37,176 [main]
>   org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext: Refreshing
>   org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext@709a7571: startup date [Tue
>   Jun 02 09:44:37 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy INFO  2015-06-02
>   09:44:43,583 [main] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager:
>   Disposing RegistryBroker ERROR 2015-06-02 09:44:43,786 [main]
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: C  at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_55]     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_55]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_55]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_55]     at
>   sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(FtpClient.java:958) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
>     at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(FtpClient.java:918)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_55]     at
>   sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1013) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
>     at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:999)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_55]     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:294)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_55]     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:393)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_55]     at
>   org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:167)
>   ~[spring-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:143)
>   ~[spring-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
>   ~[spring-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
>   ~[spring-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
>   ~[spring-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:78)
>   ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
>   ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:669)
>   ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
>   ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:86)
>   ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:105)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:135)
>   ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:90)
>   ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:187)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:310)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:330)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:155)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:256)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:78)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:100)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:152)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15)
>   ~[tooling-support-3.6.0.jar:?] INFO  2015-06-02 09:44:43,787 [main]
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App
>   'slack-notifications-esb' never started, nothing to dispose of ERROR
>   2015-06-02 09:44:43,817 [main]
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: 
>   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   + Failed to deploy artifact 'slack-notifications-esb',     +
>   + see below                                                +
>   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException:
>   UnknownHostException: C   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:196)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:62)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:129)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:57)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.guardedDeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:310)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:330)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:155)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:256)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.deployPackagedArtifact(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:78)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.deployPackedApps(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:275)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.start(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:150)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.MuleDeploymentService.start(MuleDeploymentService.java:100)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer.start(MuleContainer.java:152)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   at
>   org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:15)
>   ~[tooling-support-3.6.0.jar:?] Caused by:
>   org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Could not load properties;
>   nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: C
>   (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
>   (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:187)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   ... 14 more Caused by:
>   org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Could not load properties;
>   nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: C
>   (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:187)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   ... 14 more Caused by:
>   org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Could not load
>   properties; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: C  at
>   org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:113)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:135)
>   ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:90)
>   ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:187)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   ... 14 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could
>   not load properties; nested exception is
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: C  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:87)
>   ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
>   ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:669)
>   ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
>   ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:86)
>   ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:105)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:135)
>   ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:90)
>   ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:187)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   ... 14 more Caused by:
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: C  at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_55]     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_55]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_55]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_55]     at
>   sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(FtpClient.java:958) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
>     at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(FtpClient.java:918)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_55]     at
>   sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1013) ~[?:1.7.0_55]
>     at sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:999)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_55]     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:294)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_55]     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:393)
>   ~[?:1.7.0_55]     at
>   org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getInputStream(UrlResource.java:167)
>   ~[spring-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:143)
>   ~[spring-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
>   ~[spring-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
>   ~[spring-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
>   ~[spring-core-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:78)
>   ~[spring-beans-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:694)
>   ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:669)
>   ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
>   ~[spring-context-3.2.10.RELEASE.jar:3.2.10.RELEASE]   at
>   org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:86)
>   ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:105)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:135)
>   ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:90)
>   ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:84)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:217)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:76)
>   ~[mule-core-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]  at
>   org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:187)
>   ~[mule-module-launcher-3.6.0.jar:3.6.0]   ... 14 more INFO  2015-06-02
>   09:44:43,825 [main]
>   org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher: 
>   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
>   + Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)                    +
>   ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ INFO  2015-06-02 09:44:43,903 [main]
>   org.mule.module.launcher.StartupSummaryDeploymentListener:
>
> ---
>
> - - - - DOMAIN + - -               * - - + STATUS + - - *
>
>         ---
> - default                                       * DEPLOYED           *
>
>   ---
>
> ---
>
> - - - - APPLICATION + - -            *       - - + DOMAIN + - -       * - - + STATUS + - - *
>
>         ---
> - slack-notifications-esb                       * default                        * FAILED             *
>
>   ---

Comment: Can you also add your Mule config XML? It seems Spring is having issues loading the properties file for your project.

Comment: Where would I find that?

Comment: go to the configuration tab .. you will find the Xml generated for all the graphical design you created

Comment: Agree with @DavidDossot please add mule xml.